# pros/cons for creating own custom contract router

Tags: solidity, contract-development, uniswap, pancakeswap

I have seen some people (bots?) using custom routers/contracts for trading and tried to google this why someone wants to use custom router instead uniswap/pancakeswap.

I wonder if someone here knows reason for this? pros and cons?